# Rank ggplot Dot Plot by Point Size

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to rank a dot plot by the size of the dot which is based on a third variable. Right now I can display the dots but they will not be ranked just based on the size. I would like it so that the bigger dots are towards the top of the plot and it descends from there. Below is a sample data set and plot that illustrates my problem.

```
df <- data.frame('Pathway' = c('PW1','PW2','PW3','PW4','PW5','PW6','PW7','PW8','PW9','PW10'),
           Value = c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,4,3),
           Percent = c(1,.25,1,.75,.25,.25,.25,1,.5,1))

ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(aes(x = Value, y = Pathway, size =  Percent))
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be the `reorder()` function. You can set the order of the y categorical value based on Percent.

```
ggplot(df) +
    geom_point(aes(x = reorder(Value,Percent), y = reorder(Pathway,Percent), size =  reorder(Percent,Percent)))
```

Comment: Hm so that seems to work but there are a few random points in my full data set that are out of order. I will mess with it more but that is strange.

Comment: You are totally right, you need to re-order all of the variables.

Comment: Thank you but that still leads to the same issue and I am not sure why.